# Django Templates: Passing a django value into default_if_none in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I am trying to pass two values into django templates. I want value two to be displayed when value one is None.

`{{ gl.name|default_if_none: gl.name_two }}`

Someone Help me on how i should handle this. Thanks

Comment: It should work. What does your gl look like?

Comment: @Gejun, I later figured out that i should remove the space after the `default_if_none:`. its now working `{{ gl.name|default_if_none:gl.name_two }}`